# unable to find an inherited method for function ‘draw’ for signature ‘"bam"’

Tags: r, draw, gam

I'm running a gam in R and this error message keeps popping-up. I've loaded all the necessary packages, made the model less complex, changed the method - nothing seems to work. Has anyone had this problem before and found a solution?

```
library("gratia")
library("mgcv")

m3 <- bam(occur ~ s(temp) + 
        # sal + 
        s(DO) + 
        sed_depth + 
        # water_depth + 
        
        ave_sav + 
        s(prop_sg) + 
        # prop_ma +
        
        Season + 
        TimeOfDay + 
        
        s(ToD) + 
        s(DoY, bs = 'cc') + 
        CYR.std +
        
        # Spatial variation
        s(Longitude, Latitude, bs = 'tp') + 
        
        s(fSite, bs = "re") +
      
      data = toad, 
      method = 'fREML', 
      # knots = knots,
      # nthreads = 4, 
      discrete = TRUE, 
      family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
      select = TRUE,
      gamma = 1.5)

draw(m3,
     select = c(1,2),
     scale = "fixed")
```

Error:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘draw’ for signature ‘"bam"’
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to have just been a case of another package with the same function name of 'draw' stopping gratia from doing its thing. I re-loaded everything and it works now.

Comment: A good way to check that would be to do `gratia::draw(m3, ...)` to specifically call gratia's `draw()` command